# How can I compile my React component's styles (JSX and CSS Modules) to be used statically — as a simple imported .css file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package, css-modules, classname

### Background

I'm creating a public Node package which consists of some React UI. I'm currently using CSS Modules to scope the styles to the component, and it's all being successfully bundled with Webpack. The bundle outputs a `main.css` file.

### The ask

Since I intend to use this packaged component across many projects with different frameworks, I cannot guarantee that CSS Modules will be available. Thus, I would like to "flatten" the compiled JSX, such that the generated CSS Module classNames are *always* added at build time, rather than being conditionally added based on whether or not the CSS modules are being imported. From there I should be able to just import the compiled CSS file and call it a day.

### What I've found

- This tool seems to solve my problem, specifically using CSS Modules. This is not actively maintained though, and I wonder if there's a better solution out there.

  - https://cef62.github.io/css-modules-compiler/
  - https://cef62.github.io/css-modules-compiler/quick-start.html
- I do wonder if this is doable with some sort of PostCSS routine or a preexisting PostCSS plugin.